# How to correct Select Spool in the BAT file

Tags: sql, batch-file, cmd, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am writing a BAT file in the windows servers which will connect to the oracle and select output will be spooled to a file and output file will be placed to the network drive.

I have done this via below steps:
1) Create a bat file to connect to the oracle and execute the file.

```
sqlplus UserName/Password@Hostname:1555/Service_Name @SQL_Script_to_execute
copy generated_File_with_path network_location
```

2) Place the select query in the SQL script.

```
spool "path_to_the_saved_file";
set define off;
set heading off;
set linesize 30000;
select column_A||ColumnB|| columnC  from table;
spool off;
exit;
```

I am able to extract the query result in the output file but format is very incorrect.

I am getting lots of extra space after end of last column and few blank rows.

How Can I remove these extra spaces after the last column and in between blank lines?

> PS: I have done taken below steps till now
>
> - Removed linesize in the SQL script so that extra spaces after the last column can be avoided but it make the output file much worse.
>     Table rows were not coming in the single line.
> - Added set pagesize 50000, it indeed resolved the issue but still few blank lines were still present in the
>     file as total number of rows in the table is approx 70000.
>
>   - I am already using query as select colA|| col B || colC from table to avoid space issue.

Comment: What is datatype of those columns? Is it, by any chance, CHAR (not VARCHAR2, but CHAR)? If so, its value is right-padded with blanks up to total length of the column. Could that be the case?

Comment: Have you tried including `set pagesize 0` in your script to remove the whitespace?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the code is concatenating three (3) fields. If there is whitespace in the fields, it can be trimmed.

```
select TRIM(column_A) || TRIM(ColumnB) || TRIM(columnC) from table;
```

If all three (3) fields have nothing in them, then that would produce a blank line.

Comment: No, there is no whitespace in the fields.

Answer (score 2):

> I am getting lots of extra space after end of last column and few
>   blank rows.
>
> How Can I remove these extra spaces after the last column and in
>   between blank lines?

One easy way to is to `RTRIM` spaces after the last column as shown below. I just embedded your query in a outer query and removed the spaces.

```
SELECT
    rtrim(col1)
FROM 
( SELECT
    column_a
    || columnb
    || columnc col1
FROM TABLE );
```

Comment: Thanks XING, I will share the result soon.

Answer (score -1):

Use it like below in sqlplus:

```
SET PAGES 0 TRIMSPOOL ON FEEDBACK OFF ECHO OFF TERMOUT OFF SERVEROUTPUT OFF VERIFY OFF
spool .\filename.txt
select column_A||ColumnB|| columnC  from table;
spool off
/
```